# Print embedded infopath web part sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development

I have an embedeed web part infopath form on my site. This form has 2 views I would like to add a button that changes the form's other view 1 prints only the webpart (not the entire page).

I have looked everywhere can't find anything to accomplish this. Best i have done so far is a button on the form to change to a different view and a button that prints the entire webpage.

Answer (score 0):

What I used to do in such cases is to use JavaScript and hide unwanted page elements and call JavaScript `window.print`

You can use browser tools to locate the elements you want to hide and do something as below on the Print button click

```
$('#pageElementId').hide();
```